# How to copy/paste a Word a file that has a linked formatted text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I link some datas in a word file in order to have dynamic fields.

I do it by this way

1. I add a Text field from Under Developers - Controls - Text.
2. I write something to this text field and copy it and past special.
3. In paste special I choose Paste link - Unformatted Text and I click ok.

Everything is all right up to this point. When I type something to the text field, It changes automatically.

However, If I copy this word file and move some other folder and try to open it, I got this warning.

> This document contains one or more links to other files. Do you want
>   to update this document with the data from the linked files?

When I got this warning I check if the text fields are changed dynamically, However it doesn't.

So, the problem persist if I move the word file.

I am looking for a solution to this matter for a long time.

Comment: Sounds like it may have nothing to do with the textbox, and instead there's a file/image linked in the document someplace (vs. being Embedded). See [Break link with external document MS Word](http://superuser.com/questions/414786/break-link-with-external-document-ms-word) and see if any info there helps.

Comment: I created a blank page. I just added one text field. Copied and pasted it as special - linked. I don't have any pictures tables whatever. Maybe it is not about textfield but it is obvious that it is because of linked data. It screws up something when I copy file to somewhere else.

Comment: "pasted it as special - linked" - I missed that little tidbit in the OP because you said Paste link" instead of "Paste Linked". :)  That's why you have linked stuff in your document, because you're pasting it as "Linked".  Why not just us a regular Paste - Keep Text only?

Comment: If I paste 'unlinked text', the text cannot be dynamic. My goal is having a dynamic text-field.

Comment: Have you tried making the link a relative path and making sure that the files are copied together?

Comment: There is only one file. In a word file I just create a textfield and copy that textfield to somewhere else as linked. How can I make relative path?

Answer (score 0):

Although the kind of links you are creating can be "fixed up" using code, they are best avoided. You would probably be better off using content controls that are connected to the data store, assuming you only need to use Windows Word 2007 and later.

http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Repeating_Data.htm is a good starting point.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can solve this just by using code. I use word 2013

Comment: A good starting point is macropod's code, referenced at the bottom of this article: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154379-Word-Fields-and-Relative-Paths-to-External-Files

You will probably need to sign up to follow the link.